# Mysql 5.5.54 Duplicate entry on unique key with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, yii

We have table in production (locally I try to do same thing, everything works as expected, maybe I have newer db version).

Table contains many columns, two of them is number AND year. These columns are bound with unique constraint key.

When I do query such as

```
SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE number IS NULL  AND YEAR = 2018
```

I get more than one row. And it's not important, it's correct. [I could have 100 rows with null, 2018 for example]
But when I try to insert new record with number = null and year = 2018. I get error such as

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2018' for key 'number_year_UNIQUE'
```

One thing which comes in mind is that null in mysql is hiddenly bound with random number, and when I try to insert it's somehow becomes duplicate for new record.

As extra info is: We use Yii1 and error appears through ActiveRecord.

**EDIT**

After suggeestion added profiling got bound params

They are as follow

```
:yp13='2018', 
:yp14='',
```

Exactly same parameters are on local machine.

**EDIT**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have a unique number year `number_year_UNIQUE` which you must be inserting again

Comment: What did you mean?

Comment: you have added a unique index on number_year which means you cannot insert another record with the same year

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam, are you serious? Added photos, they are seen on screenshot

Comment: yes that is what the error states and i can see that you have a composite key added for the columns `year` and `number` as `unique` and you cant have the same pair of values for these 2 fields, i am amazed how on the first hand you added the constraint if the data was there it shouldn’t have. and if you added the data after adding the constraint , the data shouldnt be added.

Comment: @Muhammed Omer Aslam I can have even million null value at one column and million 2018 value at another, and its not a mistake, you are wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in that I tried to insert empty string '' not null value, as stated above (seen on screenshot). 
In code I had something like

```
$order = new Order();
//some other stuff
$order->number = null;
$order->save();
```

However, in rules (in newly added validation method, number became empty string)
Added scenario (Yii specific) and problem had gone.

Answer (score 1):

did you tried to run the insert query from from sql console(PhpMyAdmin or similar)?

I doubt it's an issue in the php side like the way you pass null value.